# How to generate thumbnail from .eps and .ai files?

Tags: thumbnails

How can I generate thumbnails from `.eps` and `.ai` (and `.psd`)? files and save them as a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .eps, try [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) with its [POSTSCRIPT plugin](http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows you can use the "Microsoft Document Image Writer" printer to save any document as a TIFF image File. This file can be opened in any picture/image viewer and converted.

Comment: Alternatively pressing ALT+Print Screen keys will generate a "screenshot" of the currently-focused window in the clipboard. You can "paste" the picture into any image/picture program and save in any bitmap (bmp, jpg, png, etc) format.